# How to add radio buttons and input fields using angularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to add both input fields and corresponding radio buttons to my project using angularJS. Means when I click add, it will create one input field and 3 corresponding radio buttons together, as below picture. I could able to add input fields successfully when I click add. But having trouble in creating radio buttons also when I click add the iput field's placeholder should display input 1 and when click add again should display input 2 like that. Can someone help me on it. Following is my code.

[image]

Html portion:

```
<table class="table">
<tr class="tr_class">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td align="center"><b>functional check </b></td>
    <td align="center"><b>XXissue</b></td>
    <td align="center"><b>YY risk</b></td>
</tr>

<tr class="tr_class">
    <td class="td_class"><div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">input 1</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="input 1">
    </div> <br/></td>
    <td> </td>
    <td align="center"><input type="radio" name="a1"></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="radio" name="a1"></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="radio" name="a1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Check2</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="input 2">
    </div> <br/></td>
    <td></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="radio" name="a2"></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="radio" name="a2" ></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="radio" name="a2" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">input 3</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="input 3">
    </div> <br/></td>
    <td></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="radio" name="a3"></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="radio" name="a3"></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="radio" name="a3"></td>
</tr>

<br><br>

<tr>

    <td><div ng-controller="AlertDemoCtrl">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="input 3" ng-repeat="alert in alerts"
               type="{{success.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)">{{success.msg}}<br></input>
        <button type="button" class='btn btn-info' ng-click="addAlert()">+Add input</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger">Reset</button>
    </div> <br><br><br></td></tr>
```

and my angularJS part:

```
{{ ngapp }}.controller('AlertDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.alerts = [
  ];

  $scope.addAlert = function() {
    $scope.alerts.push({msg: 'Another alert!'});
  };

  $scope.closeAlert = function(index) {
    $scope.alerts.splice(index, 1);
  };
});
```

Comment: where is the declaration for the radio buttons in the HTML?

Comment: wait, now you posted static radio buttons but your question was about dynamic buttons?  in fact, those input boxes and radio buttons you posted in the update aren't even connected to any angular model at all.

Comment: Ya. But am not sure how to add dynamic radio buttons. That's my main concern

Comment: well, it seems like you are thinking about this backwards.  instead of trying to come up with how to dynamically add DOM elements, you should be thinking about how the data you are trying to represent is structured.  If you have the data figured out, the DOM will be easy to match.

Comment: what data is it you are trying to gather with these buttons and input boxes? what relationship do the radio groups have with the input box?

Comment: Am quiet new in programming field, getting my base. What am trying here is to once i add the input field, there will be 3 radio buttons corresponding to that. Can select only one of the radio button. like that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88334/discussion-between-claies-and-blackwindow).

Comment: I'll still be around for a bit, if you want to come back and have a discussion in chat.

Comment: Am not able to continue chat because of some firewall settings. I will get back to you soon. Thanks Claies

Answer (score 1):

Refer the below attached [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KByadw?p=preview), I have derived you an answer on how to modify DOM in order to add / remove elements from the current view.

Even though this will elaborate how to add elements, the removal process would be the same. Just remove the required element from the element list.

This is how you add radio buttons dynamically.

```
<td ng-repeat="answer in question.answersList track by $index">
  <input type="radio" name="{{$parent.$index}}" ng-value="1" ng-model="answer.is_correct">
</td>

$scope.addRow = function() {
  $scope.questionList.push({
        "question_num": $scope.questionList.length+1,
        "answersList": [
            {
                "is_correct": "0",
                "answer_text": "Answer 1",
                "feedback": "Feedback 1"
            },
            {
                "is_correct": "0",
                "answer_text": "Answer 2",
                "feedback": "Feedback 2"
            },
            {
                "is_correct": "1",
                "answer_text": "Answer 3",
                "feedback": "Feedback 3"
            }
        ],
        "question_text": "Sample Question" + ($scope.questionList.length+1)
    });
}
```

Comment: But it returns an error as follows  `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.bootstrap.demo due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.bootstrap.demo' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.`

Comment: Comment the unnecessary line in the code as below `<!-- <script src="scripts/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script> -->`

Comment: The error is not there but its just not working.. cant understand why

Comment: Can you prepare a plunker with your implementation. Also hope you did refer mine.

Comment: I have enhanced the answer with `Add / Remove` elements from the DOM based on user input. Refer the modified answer.

Comment: How did things going on. Were you able to resolve your issues?